# Get label for given level of factor in R

Tags: r

Given this factor:

```
> str(some$factor)
 Factor w/ 398 levels "13:23","13:24",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

> levels(some$factor)
  [1] "13:23" "13:24" "13:25" "13:26" "13:27" ...

> labels(some$factor)
  [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5" ...
```

how can I get a label (e.g. "2") for a given level (e.g. "13:24")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create an index with `match` to extract the corresponding `labels` in `base R`

```
labels(some$factor)[match("13:24", levels(some$factor))]
#[1] "2"
```

#### data

```
some <- data.frame(factor  = c("13:23", "13:24", "13:25"), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. And for multiple levels one can pass a vector to that function: `labels(some$factor)[match(c("13:24", "13:25"), levels(some$factor))]`